# Sorensen Pat #6,960,316 - patent infringement

Tags: prior-art-request, post-grant, us6960316

Issued US Patent No: 6,960,316
Injection-molded plastic container or closure with turned-under rim and method of injection-molding same

I am searching for any help locating prior art for the afore mentioned Patent. I have been producing a product since 1995 for which I am now being attacked due to a 2002 Patent and a troll.

Comment: As long as it has the patent # and states that the poster is looking for help finding prior art it has enough information to "properly research" the patent reference.

Comment: I'd say that a prior art claim is implied in the court filing of 05/25/12 that can be found here: https://docs.rpxcorp.com/lits/574/8364/ctdce-97258.pdf?Signature=CEvPwUtwSVaC99XJCdGR7MZNsxI%3D&Expires=1435440400&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI2UWKALIEYBVOKDA
It's the initial complaint in Mayborn USA Inc. v. Sorensen Research & Dev Trust. It seeks a Declaratory Judgment that the patent is not infringed upon NOT because of prior art, but rather because Mayborn doesn't use any of the manufacturing methods specified in the patent's claims. In January 2013, the case was DISMISSED at Mayborn's request.

Comment: If above link doesn't work, a working one can be found by clicking "view complaint" at https://search.rpxcorp.com/lit/ctdce-97258 - NO login is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your 1995 product prior art to this patent filed in 2002?  Did Sorenson R&D provide a draft claim chart in which it attempted to read the patent onto your product?  That would be quite useful to you and several others if it did.